# server can't find 10.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa(NXDOMAIN)

Tags: ubuntu

when I use command `nslookup` on server - it works for IP and for DNS. But on client(client gets all information from server(dhcp)) I've got such error when I use `nslookup 192.168.1.10`

```
 server can't find 10.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa:NXDOMAIN
```

Client's IP - 192.168.1.10
Server's IP - 192.168.1.1

Comment: It would help if you posted the nameserver logs. Preferably after you activated verbose logging.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the DNS server explicitly. That way you can rule out the possibility that `nslookup` on your server is querying a different nameserver than the one on your client.

You specify the name server as the second argument to `nslookup`. (See `man nslookup`.)

Comment: resolv.conf contains `nameserver 192.168.1.1` on client(192.168.1.10) and `nameserver 192.168.1.1` on server(192.168.1.1) in resolv.conf. And even when I try `nslookup 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.1` it still says `NXDOMAIN`